# $ rvm get head && rvm reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I inserted the following "$ rvm get head && rvm reload" and got the output below.  It says that directories are missing and to run rvmsudo to fix my issues.  Can someone explain what directories am I supposed to create?  What is "rvmsudo"?

Based on the output, does this mean that this did not run properly? at the end, it notes.. "Upgrade of RVM in /usr/local/rvm/ is complete."

**Output:**

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   185  100   185    0     0    199      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   417
100 10009  100 10009    0     0   7016      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 78811
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch master
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   125  100   125    0     0    261      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1179
100 1125k  100 1125k    0     0   640k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 1238k

Upgrading the RVM installation in /usr/local/rvm/
mkdir: /usr/local/share/man/man1: Permission denied
stat: /usr/local/share/man/man1: stat: No such file or directory
chown: /usr/local/share/man/man1: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/share/man/man1/rvm.1: No such file or directory


    Please run the installer using rvmsudo to fix file permissions

stat: /usr/local/share/man/man1/rvm.1: stat: No such file or directory
chown: /usr/local/share/man/man1/rvm.1: No such file or directory
mkdir: /usr/local/share/man/man1: Permission denied
stat: /usr/local/share/man/man1: stat: No such file or directory
chown: /usr/local/share/man/man1: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/share/man/man1/rvm.1.gz: No such file or directory


    Please run the installer using rvmsudo to fix file permissions

stat: /usr/local/share/man/man1/rvm.1.gz: stat: No such file or directory
chown: /usr/local/share/man/man1/rvm.1.gz: No such file or directory
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/XXXXXX/.bashrc /Users/XXXXXX/.zshenv.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/XXXXXX/.bash_profile /Users/XXXXXX/.zprofile.

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.

.....

# In case of any issues read output of 'rvm requirements' and/or 'rvm notes'

Upgrade of RVM in /usr/local/rvm/ is complete.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter

```
rvm -v
```

and get

```
rvm 1.16.12 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

then rvm is installed.  If it did not install properly you can use

```
rvm implode
```

That will remove it and allow you start from scratch.

```
rvm get stable
```

This is will get you the latest stable version.

As for what rvmsudo is, here is a great explanation

http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/qt/Rvm-And-Sudo.htm

Comment: I see that I have `rvm 1.16.16 (master)`.  Do you recommend that I install `1.16.12`?  Is there a difference between the versions? Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend ALWAYS use the most stable version of anything, whether it be Ruby, Rails, RVM, etc.  Here is a better explanation of the difference between the two. http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2012/rvm-stable-and-more/